# How to write Xpath where we have lot of White spaces in front of the button text

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="btn-group icon-btn">
    <div class="wrap-btn">
        <button ng-class="{active : hasOptions('3',option)}" class="organge-btn ng-binding" type="button">

                       Employee
                     </button>
                  </div>
```

I have HTML code mentioned above and and I see there is lot of white blank spaces in front of the button called 'Employee' and I want to write XPATH for the button called 'Employee' and I have used the below three XPATHS but it doesn't work, Any idea how to fix it to identify the element using a unique XPATH.

1. `//button[@type='button' ]`
2. `//button[@type='button' and @class='organge-btn ng-binding']`
3. `//div[@class='wrap-btn']//button[@type='button' and @class='organge-btn ng-binding']`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry i meant i doesn't identify the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
`//button[normalize-space(text())='Employee']`

Answer (score 0):

To select the button which `text()` value consists of the value `Employee`, use this XPath-1.0 expression

```
//button[normalize-space(.)='Employee']
```

Comment: What @Sooraj Sathianandan gave as an answer is nearly identical to this answer, but given at a later time. I wonder why he did it...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried all these three below and all worked but i need to understand the difference between 3 of them, i heard they three behave differently? any ideas, but thanks for your answers they work

```
//button[normalize-space()='Employee']
//button[normalize-space(text())='Employee']
//button[normalize-space(.)='Employee']
```